# Can I upgrade my attributes for my character later in game in Pillars of Eternity?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

When creating a character I can invest points in six attributes:

- Might
- Constitution
- Dexterity
- Perception
- Intellect
- Resolve

Can I upgrade those when leveling up or do they remain the same over the whole course of the game?

Comment: @Deltharis While the linked question answers of upgrading the stats, it does say nothing about dead locked stats in terms of progression in the game due to a trap  build.

Comment: The whole design of the game is built around avoiding/preventing trap builds.

Comment: @k0pernikus I didn't read that far into it - reading the title and glancing most of the details should be enough - trap builds could use their own question.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Could you please elaborate on that in the follow up question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211796/can-i-make-my-character-a-trap-build-creating-them-in-pillar-of-eternity